# How to show cross button in starting before typing in text field in jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

Can we show cross button on text field (which is display after writing some text in text field ) I need to display on starting If I click that button it remove placeholder .

http://jsfiddle.net/naveennsit/prSpX/1/

Here is code

```
<div data-role="fieldcontain">
    <label for="name">Text Input:</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="" data-clear-btn="true" placeholder="Test" />
</div>
```

Comment: Thats a strange requirement. You want to remove the placeholder when clicked on the cross button?

Comment: Mean At first time when User is not not writing anything , or My requirement is that display cross button

Comment: I just think what it does if user click cross button (so I think remove placeholder)

Comment: But the cross button(clear button) is to clear the text entered...

Comment: Yes .That I know is it possible we show it on display ?